# how to handle database null error(already used iif something is null)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem

I have two table and I left join the tow table.

As you know, it may have null value

I use the IIf to handle the null value, it's work

But when I user the Server.UrlDecode function, it have a error said that can't encode the null value.

`<%# IIf(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"certName") Is System.DBNull.Value , "-----" ,    Server.UrlDecode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"certName"))) %>`

how can i fix the problem,or hidden this error message?Thank You

Answer (score 0):

IIF evaluates both the 2nd and 3rd arguments it is passed and only returns the one that corresponds to the true/false value of the 1st argument. So even though you're checking for the VBNull value, you will still get an error from the third argument because it is evaluated. Try using IF() instead, which short circuits and only evaluates the relevant argument.

Comment: how can I use the if() in <%# .... %>?
I use <%# if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"certName") Is System.DBNull.Value) %>
-------
<% Else %>
<% End If %>
But an error occur